# Change main method in Code::Blocks?

Tags: c++, winapi, codeblocks

I switched from *main* to *WinMain* and Code::Blocks is searching for *main*. How do I fix this? This is probably a stupid question but I can't find it online.

**UPDATE @JBL**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "def.h" //This defines a few things
#include <windows.h>
#include <gl/gl.h>
#include "glcontext.h" //This defines some OpenGL/Win32 functions

using namespace std;

BOOL WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine,
int nCmdShow)
{

 }
```

Comment: Could you show the code ? (You can skip the main() content).

Comment: if your codeblocks is using minGW compiler you need to link with -mwindows switch

Answer (score 1):

if you add the following to the Microsoft linker options:

/subsystem:windows /ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartupNote that this is not necessary for the GNU toolchain.

Still for the Microsoft tools you can alternatively add this to your main file:

.#ifdef _MSC_VER
.#    pragma comment(linker, "/subsystem:windows /ENTRY:WinMainCRTStartup")
.#endif